# Using AppCompat-Toolbar in Xamarin.Android without deriving from AppCompatActivity?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I want to add a toolbar to an activity in my Xamarin.Android app. This should work in older versions of Android, so I am implementing this functionality with the  Android Support v7 AppCompat library.

In order to make the toolbar act like an action bar, I would have to call SetSupportActionBar (seen [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar/Supportv7Toolbar/MainActivity.cs).

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.main);

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar> (Resource.Id.toolbar);

        //Toolbar will now take on default actionbar characteristics
        SetSupportActionBar (toolbar);

        SupportActionBar.Title = "Hello from Appcompat Toolbar";

        // ...
    }
}
```

The method SetSupportActionBar is from AppCompatActivity, which is why the Activity in the sample code derives from that class in the first place.

Now, is there a way to make use of AppCompatActivity's functionality such as SetSupportActionBar if I can't derive my Activity from AppCompatActivity?

My activity must extend another base class to function properly.

Comment: AppCompatActivity is basically a wrapper for AppCompatDelegate (which actually does all the heavy lifting). This is in Java, but I'm sure you can translate https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3

Comment: In MvvmCross we used this too for a while back. See this example: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/d4f329e114e4cd65d8dd820d9c690db575361438/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.AppCompat/MvxCachingFragmentActivityCompat.cs

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but here is the code if people still need it:

```
        private AppCompatDelegate appCompat;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        appCompat = AppCompatDelegate.Create(this, null);
        appCompat.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        appCompat.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Invite);

        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        appCompat.SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

Used the link from Killman [Java explanation](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3)